# How to prove, that this is a bounded linear operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let us have 
$$L^3[0,2] \to \mathbb{C}, f \to \phi(f)=\int_0^1 e^x f(x) dx$$

Show, that this is a bounded linear operator, and search the norm of $\phi$!

My approach:

When solving a task like this, we first always searched for a $q$, with the following attitude:

$$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1 \to L^p \equiv L^p (1<p)$$

We have $p=3$, so $q=\frac32$ will do.

Then we can decide the norm in the space $L_q$.

$$||\phi||=||\alpha||_q=\sqrt[q]{\int_0^1 |\alpha(t)|^q dt}$$

In our case, we solved $f \to \int_0^1 f(x^2) dx$, in that case, we used $x^2=t \to \sqrt{t}=x \to \frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{t}} \to \alpha=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{t}}$.

I am stuck here, I don't know how to calculate this, and how to move forward.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just apply Holder's inequality to $$\lvert \phi(f) \rvert \le \int^1_0 e^x \lvert f(x)\rvert dx.$$ This will give a bound on $\| \phi \|$.

Comment: In the problem you write $L^3[0,2]$ but all of the integrals are over $[0,1]$, which is it?

Comment: The task says $L^3[0,2]$, and the integral is $[0,1]$ so I don't really know. I guess $[0,1]$. :)

Comment: anyway $\|f\|_{L^3([0,1])} \le \|f\|_{L^3([0,2])}$